# ITV.com no longer works from Ubuntu

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, streaming, drm

Since the beginning of the year (2020) I can't get onto the ITV.com site without it saying my browser settings need updating. The screen that takes me to says I need to change my DRM settings to enable DRM but the settings it wants are already set (applies to FF and Chrome).

The helpline says they don't support Linux. But they used to before

I was previously able to load some codec files which did the job - are there some new ones?

Thanks for any help..

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is applicable to you as this is the first time I've tried the site in linux. I got videos to play by disabling hardware acceleration in Firefox (Lubuntu), hope this helps you!

Update:
It only works during the commercial breaks!